# How to prevent jQuery onload flicker unobtrusively?

Tags: jquery, tabs, load, flicker, unobtrusive

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs. How should I prevent the flicker of loading content while also making sure that the content is visible when javascript is disabled?

I've tried adding a .js class to the body when the doc is loaded but as the tabs are loaded at the same time as the class being added there is still the flicker of content.

```
#container{display:none;}

<div id="container">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs').tabs();
  $('#container').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what I do. put a class of `no-js` on your html tag and then put the following code just after the html tag:

```
<script>
    // Sets 'js' on html element and removes 'no-js' if present (here to prevent flashing)
    (function(){
        document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/, '$1$2') + (' js '); 
    })();
</script>
```

This method allows you to have other classes on your `html` tag if required. Use the `no-js` class in your styles for pages that don't have js enabled.

styles example:

```
#container {
  display:none;
}
.no-js #container
{ 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: inside head or between html and head?

Comment: as long as its before the container div it doesn't matter. But I would put it just after the html tag (between html and head)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. This works great and also allows for other classes in the html tag should they be required.

Answer (score 5):

```
<html class="nojs">
  ...
  <head>
     <script>
       document.documentElement.className = "js";
     </script>
  </head>

  ...
  <style>
  #container {display:none;}
  .nojs #container { display: block;}
  </style>
```

this will make your content visible even when js is not available on your device. This approach is almost the same performed by H5BP + Modernizr and, as aside benefit, it will prevent the JS FOUC (flash of unstyled content due to js later execution).

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm gonna try it now :)

Comment: +1 Ensure that you embed it, rather than linking it as the external resource will again end up causing the FOUC.

Comment: is `<script>` = `<script type='text/javascript'>`?

Comment: `type='text/javascript'` is not necessary. See my answer below for a more robust solution.

Comment: `type` is not necessary, in all modern browser can be omitted

Comment: @DaveHaigh in what your solution is more robust? It seems really identical to this solution I wrote... or am I missing something?

Comment: as explained in my answer - you can have other classes on the html tag and they won't be overwritten by your `js` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="tabs">
  <script>$('#tabs').addClass('js');</script><!-- added this line -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs').tabs().show(); // changed this line
  $('#container').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for above ideas to solve the on load flicker.
As browsers try to render markup as soon as possible, this should be avoided for some (huge) jquery-ui content elements as jquery-ui Tabs.

This solution works for me:

```
<html>
...
  <head>
  ...
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs_container").tabs();

        // force *initialized* #tab_container to be displayed
        $("#tabs_container").show();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  ...

  <body>
    ...
    <!-- avoid unstyled tabs to be displayed using "display: none" at markup -->
    <div id="tabs_container" style="display: none;">
      <!-- (huge) tabs content -->
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
<script>
$("#container").hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs').tabs();
  $('#container').show();
});
</script>
```

The container is hidden as it is loaded and when the document is ready and tabs are done, you can show the container.